# How can I test for an empty Breeze predicate?

Tags: breeze

I'm using Breeze to filter data requested on the client. My code looks a little like this:

**Client - Creating Filter Predicate**

```
var predicates = [];
var criteriaPredicate = null;
$.each(selectedFilterCriteria(), function (index, item) {
    criteriaPredicate = (index == 0)
        ? breeze.Predicate.create('criteriaId', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Equals, item)
        : criteriaPredicate.or('criteriaId', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Equals, item);
if (breeze.Predicate.isPredicate(criteriaPredicate)) {
    predicates.push(criteriaPredicate);
}

// Repeat for X Filter Criteria

var filter = breeze.Predicate.and(predicates);
return context.getAll(filter, data);
```

**Client - Context Query**

```
function getAll(predicate, dataObservable) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Data');
    if (breeze.Predicate.isPredicate(predicate)) {
        query = query.where(predicate);
    }
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(failure);
}
```

**Issue**

I'm having an issue with the request because, if there are no filters set, I apply an "empty" predicate (due to the `var filter = breeze.Predicate.and([])` line) resulting in a request like `http://mysite/api/app/Data?$filter=`. The request is an invalid OData query since the value of the $filter argument cannot be empty.

Is there a good way for me to check for an empty predicate? I know I can refactor my client code to not use a predicate unless there is at least one filterable item, but I thought I would check first to see if I overlooked some property or method on the Breeze Predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your predicate or filter object is an array just test the length.  If it is zero then don't apply the where clause.  You have already defined query so there is no need to do anything else.

```
function getAll(predicate, dataObservable) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Data');
    if (breeze.Predicate.isPredicate(predicate) && predicate.length !==0) {
        query = query.where(predicate);
    }
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(failure);
}
```

**EDIT**

In your question I realize you stated you can refactor your code after I provided this answer.  Without going into too much detail, I choose to create re-usable queries that can be dynamically created to reduce how much code must be changed if I change my model.  It seems that is what you are trying to do as well.  I would recommend building a query that is robust enough to take in predicates, an orderBy, a take, and anything else you *may* use later, and then handle if the passed in objects or variables are null.  I feel this is the best approach for writing reusable code.  Example -

```
function getEntities(dataObservable, predicates, orderby, take, local) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Data');

    if (local) {
        query = query.executeQueryLocally();
    }
    if (orderBy) {
        query = query.orderBy(orderby);
    }
    if (take) {
        query = query.take(take);
    }
    if (breeze.Predicate.isPredicate(predicate) && predicate.length !==0) {
        query = query.where(predicate);
    }
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(failure);
}
```

By doing this each subsequent time you need to filter data you can define methods in your data service or directly from your view model to follow the fetch pattern.  Now when you go back and change your model or something you have one query to adjust instead of 20.